# what is SDK Patch Applier in android SDK Tool?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

what is this tool for and why we need it ? I search a lot but don't get any word about this new  tool i found in my sdk tool list.
[image]

Comment: Anybody knows what it is and what is does in 2023?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug and should not be visible:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216501

By the issue subcomponent label maybe something to do with the SDK manager's internal use of [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/).

Comment: Okay so it's a known issue in AOSP. Tnq

Comment: Okay, but what is it?